# HTTP Post Request Timeout is Ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, iis, https

I'm trying to make a post request from my Angular app (Angular 6). 
In some cases, the response might be longer than the default timeout (which is exactly 2 minutes), so in these cases I modified the timeout manually to be longer. 
When running the app on localhost, everything works perfectly. 
Unfortunately, once I build the file and deploy it to our test site, it ignores the timeout and I get an error. 
My Angular app is sending the request to an **asp.net proxy** server which runs on **IIS 8**, which sends the request to the an **asp.net server** that runs on **IIS 8** as well (The Angular app is also on **IIS 8**).
The proxy server has a default timeout of 01:40 minutes, so it is also modified. According to the logs, it waits the expected amount of time, so it seems like the problem is in the client or in the IIS configuration.

This is what I tried so far:

**Client Side (Angular 6):**

```
import { mergeMap, timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

apiPost(actionName, requestParams = {}, handleError = true, httpHeaders = null, timoutInMs = 120000) { 
    return this.post(actionName, requestParams, httpHeaders)
    .pipe(timeout(timoutInMs),
      mergeMap((result: any) => {
        if (result.isSucceeded === true) {
          return of(result.content);
        } else {
          return this.handleError(result, handleError);
        }
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        return this.handleError(error, handleError);
      })
    );
  }
```

And also tried to set the timeout through the request headers:

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

apiPost(actionName, requestParams = {}, handleError = true, httpHeaders = null, timoutInMs = 120000) { 
    httpHeaders = {...httpHeaders, timeout: `${timoutInMs}`}
    return this.post(actionName, requestParams, httpHeaders)
    .pipe(mergeMap((result: any) => {
        if (result.isSucceeded === true) {
          return of(result.content);
        } else {
          return this.handleError(result, handleError);
        }
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        return this.handleError(error, handleError);
      })
    );
  }
```

And the same on the post method itself:

```
post(actionName, requestParams = {}, customCallHeaders?: Object, timeoutinMs: number = 120000): Observable<Object> {
        return this.http.post(
            `${this.getBaseUrl()}${actionName}`,
            requestParams,
            { headers: this.getHeaders(customCallHeaders) }
        ).pipe(timeout(timeoutInMs);
    }
```

All the implementations above were tested separately.

In the IIS (both Proxy and API), The following settings were changed:

1. **Connection Time-out** (seconds) is set to 1,000 seconds (Right click on the website -> Advanced Settings -> Expand "Connection Limits").
2. **Script Timeout value** set to 00:05:00 (in local computer node, expand Web Sites, select the appropriate web site and double-click ASP in the right-hand panel. In the ASP window, expand 'Limits Properties' and change the Script Timeout value).
3. **Idle Time-out (minutes)** is set to 20 (Open IIS, On the left side, select "Application Pools". On the right side, right-click this application pool and select Advanced Settings).
4. **CGI Timeout** is set to 00:05:00 (in IIS , double-click CGI icon and increase "Time-out")
5. **executionTimeout** is set to 00:10:50 (in local computer node, select "Configuration Editor", under section choose system.web and then httpRuntime).

EDIT:

While the HTTP request returns a (failed) net:: ERR_FAILED, I can see an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" message in the console. I thought I'd mention it because it's odd, but I don't believe the timeout is related to CORS as the website has plenty of requests from the API and I am receiving no such messages. Also, I've set the allowed origin to "*" and am still receiving the same message.

Comment: Is the failure due do to time or size?

Comment: You set the time value in millisecond timoutInMs = 120000 in your code which means it's 2 minutes. try to increase it.

Comment: @jdweng the failure is due to time.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal It's the default value. The function is called with higher value than 120000.

Comment: try to use the fiddler or network monitor to capture the request for both backend and server.

Comment: Are you using a WAF? Sometimes they can have their own timeouts